# Changed css() value is not captured by the next statement. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
let tog = true;

$("#toggle_form").click(()=> {
    toggle()
})

const toggle = () => { 
    if(tog === true) { 
        
        $("#toggle_form").text("Register")
        $("#LoginForm").css("opacity", "1")
        $("#RegForm").css("left", "-100%")
        
        $("#LoginForm").css("left", "0px")
        $("#RegForm").css("transition", "left 0.5s")
        $("#LoginForm").css("transition", "left 0.5s")

        console.log($("#RegForm").css("left"))

        if($("#RegForm").css("left") === "-300px") { 
            console.log($("#RegForm").css("left") + " HERE")
            $("#RegForm").css("opacity", "0")
        }

        tog = !tog;
    } else {
        console.log($("#RegForm").css("left"))
        $("#toggle_form").text("Login")
        $("#RegForm").css("opacity", "1")
        $("#LoginForm").css("left", "-100%")
        $("#RegForm").css("left", "0px")
        $("#RegForm").css("transition", "left 0.5s")
        $("#LoginForm").css("transition", "left 0.5s")

        if($("#LoginForm").css("left") === "-300px") { 
            $("#LoginForm").css("opacity", "0")
        }
        
        tog = !tog;
    }
}
```

```css
* { 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form { 
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid;
 padding: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#RegForm {
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
}


#LoginForm {
    top: 0;
    left:-100%;
    opacity: 0;
}


.input_field { 
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper { 
    
    text-align: center;
}

.SubBtn { 
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color:rgb(10, 157, 248);
    border: none;
    color: white;
}

.wrapper label { 
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#container { 
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 100px;
    left:200px;
}

#toggle_form { 
    position: relative;
    top:-50px;
    left: 130px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <button id="toggle_form">Login</button>
    <form id="RegForm" class="form">
        <div id="username-wrapper" class="wrapper">
            <label for="inp_username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="reg_username" class="input_field" name="inp_username">
        </div>
        <div id="password-wrapper" class="wrapper">
            <label for="inp_password">Password</label>
            <input type="text" id="reg_password" class="input_field" name="inp_password">
        </div>
        
        <button id="SubmitReg" type="submit" class="SubBtn">Register</button>
    </form>
    
    <form id="LoginForm" class="form">
        <div id="username-wrapper" class="wrapper">
            <label for="inp_username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="login_username" class="input_field" name="inp_username">
        </div>
        <div id="password-wrapper" class="wrapper">
            <label for="inp_password">Password</label>
            <input type="text" id="login_password" class="input_field" name="inp_password">
        </div>
        
        <button id="SubmitLogin" type="submit" class="SubBtn">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

So, I am toggling between `#LoginForm` and `#RegForm`, and I want to make the `("left", "-100%")` element `opacity 0`, but the issue I am having is that, the `opacity` is executed first before the position movement, which results in not seeing the movement of the element at all.

For that reason, I made a condition to only execute the `opacity` once `("left") === "-300px")`, which is `-100%` in `px`, but it's not working again, because, for some reason, `("left", "-100%")` is not captured by the condition. The `console.log()` shows that `left` remains `0px`. Putting the `console.log()` at the beginning of the `else()` shows that `left` is now `-300px`, so that means, `left` has become `-300px`, but it's just not captured in the same `if` block.

I've also experimented by making the conditional value `0px`, `if($("#RegForm").css("left") === "0px")`, and the `opacity` is once again executed before the movement, which means, the condition is met and the statements inside executed BEFORE this `$("#RegForm").css("left", "-100%")` statement is executed. Why?

Why is this happening? Do you have any ideas how can I prevent this? The only explanation that I think of is that, the `css()` is changing too quickly to get captured by the next statements inside the same block.

Comment: Please also add some html https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I don't think it's necessary, and I feel it's a bit too private, but I did it anyway. Have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let tog = true;

$("#toggle_form").click(()=> {
    toggle()
})

const toggle = () => { 
    if(tog === true) { 
        
        $("#toggle_form").text("Register")
        $("#LoginForm").css("opacity", "1")
        $("#RegForm").css("left", "-100%")
        
        $("#LoginForm").css("left", "0px")
        $("#RegForm").css("transition", "all 0.5s")
        $("#LoginForm").css("transition", "all 0.5s")

        console.log($("#RegForm").css("left"))

        setTimeout(function()
                             {
                                    $("#RegForm").css("opacity", "0");
                                     $("#RegForm").css("transition", "all 0.25s");
                             }, 350);
        tog = !tog;
        
    } else {
        console.log($("#RegForm").css("left"))
        $("#toggle_form").text("Login")
        $("#RegForm").css("opacity", "1")
        $("#LoginForm").css("left", "-100%")
        $("#RegForm").css("left", "0px")
        $("#RegForm").css("transition", "left 0.5s")
        $("#LoginForm").css("transition", "left 0.5s")


        setTimeout(function(){
                                  $("#LoginForm").css("opacity", "0");
                                  $("#LoginForm").css("transition", "all 0.25s");
                             }, 350);
        
        
        tog = !tog;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/NickU/n9t6wgL3/2/

Comment: So, you're solution is to use a `setTimeout()`? Do you have any explanation as to why is the problem happening in the first place? Why is the `css()` changes not captured?

Comment: Please take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/NickU/n9t6wgL3/1/
You can see how $("#RegForm").css("left") is changing .

Comment: This condition  if($("#LoginForm").css("left") === "-300px") is true only after 0.5sec

Comment: Yes, that was my understanding too. It takes a bit longer for the statement to be resolved. I am guessing that's because it's making a reference to the stylesheet.

Comment: $("#LoginForm").css("left")  is the direct refence to the inner element style, not to the stylesheet. 'Transition' is changing this value during 0.5sec.

Comment: What do you mean `during` 0.5 sec? When `$("#RegForm").css("left", "-100%")` this is executed, it's not resolved just 2 lines below. It takes longer time to get resolved. What does transition has to do with this? If you instead assign a different value to some variable, it will get captured on the next line, but when changing `css()` value, it's not. So, there's clearly a delay, and that's why `opacity` is instantly made 0. But why is `opacity` executed FIRST before the position movement?

Comment: `opacity` is defined at the bottom, yet executed BEFORE `$("#RegForm").css("left", "-100%")` this. Why?

Comment: Or do you mean to say that, `$("#RegForm").css("left", "-100%")` this is executed first, but because of the `transition` it takes 0.5 seconds to take take into effect, and so, before it's executed, `opacity` is executed, thus making the element `opacity 0`? I think I get it now.

Comment: Yes, you have achieved the entry level of JavaScript samadhi. :)